# Help in Handling multiple classes in independent categorical variables and improve performance

Tags: machine-learning, python, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, many-categories

The dataset has 4 categorical and 1 numerical variable and a timestamp variable. Out of 4, three categorical variables are having more than 100 categories.

I tried doing one-hot encoding on the whole dataset using "pd.get_dummies()" method and the number of columns increased from 6 to 6000. And the time consumption to do the dummy variables took more than 3 minutes.

When you want to use these variables to build an unsupervised model using machine learning to detect anomalies, how should the categorical variables be handled if you have a dataset of a million rows? Should this be considered as a time-series data but you can data for every day but not recorded in fixed intervals? What models can be applied to this kind of dataset?

Comment: Reduce the number of categories, 100 is way too much and overly partitions your data. Also, if your data is time dependent then this could be a task for time series analysis.

Comment: Use sparse matrix methods.

Comment: @user2974951 Yes, I do have  a time variable, but more than 15 transactions occur within a minute with a difference in Nanoseconds. So, I thought I could not consider it a time-series. Do you think it is time series. Say for example, you can see a lot of transactions in a minute coming into VISA system for activation of VISA gift cards from different stores, or online where they use them. My data is also similar. it does not have data stored by regular time intervals

Comment: Yes it is still time series, however it is continuous time series, which is much harder to deal with. Regardless, you still have a lot of categories which you should probably reduce to make the problem more manageable. Either grouping the categories or using some dimensionality reduction technique such as PCA.